# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown is not working as expected in my Blazor application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, bootstrap-5

When I first load my Blazor project, it comes up at `https://localhost:5003/`.

I have six pages annotated with `@page`. On one page `Reader.razor` I am using a Bootstrap NavBar with Dropdown.

```
@page "/reader"
<div class="container" id="myContainer" aria-labelledby="fullMessageBodyLabel">
    <div class="bg-dark text-light">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h6 class="card-title" id="myLabel"> Some Label Text Here ...</h6>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="2em" height="2em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.59 5.59L18 7l-6 6l-6-6l1.41-1.41L12 10.17l4.59-4.58m0 6L18 13l-6 6l-6-6l1.41-1.41L12 16.17l4.59-4.58z" fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu Item #1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu Item #2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu Item #3</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu Item #4</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu Item #5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    // Code here ...
}
```

[image: My Bootstrap NavBar Dropdown]

Here is the problem I am having. If I navigate to my page like so:

```
https://localhost:5003/reader?id=1234&value=somevalue
```

Then click on the dropdown link (the down chevron .SVG), Blazor sends me back to here:

```
https://localhost:5003/
```

Then, when I click the browser back button to go here again:

```
https://localhost:5003/reader?id=1234&value=somevalue
```

And click the dropdown link again, the dropdown will function as expected ... until I refresh/reload the page.

What do I need to do to get Blazor from sending me back to the root page on the NavBar Dropdown click?

Comment: You may want to remove the '#' specified in the src of the anchor tag. Or rather, remove the anchor tag completely and use something like a span in its place. If that still causes the same behavior problem, let me know.

Comment: @Dennis1679 I changed the anchor tag to this: `<span role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">` but the dropdown doesn't drop down any longer.

Comment: @Dennis1679 I found out what my issue was and posted an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what was going on with my project.

Before this task, I read and followed the layout example **[HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-5.0)**.

Even before that, I had some issues with my JavaScript not working at all, then I found out I was loading my 3rd party libraries incorrectly. So, in my `MainLayout.razor` I had this bit of code:

```
[Inject]
IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/popper/popper.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/JavaScript.js");
    }
}
```

After reading the "ASP.NET Core Blazor layouts" document and implementing it in my code, the JavaScript was not loading in my `Reader.razor` page. This is because I had moved `OnAfterRenderAsync` to the to-be-included layout page itself, which is only included in two "main" pages, but not my `Reader.razor` page.

I tried putting it back into the `MainLayout.razor` but, for some reason, the JavaScript now only worked in my `Reader.razor` page and not with the two other pages containing the `@layout` annotation.

So, I had to find a place to put the code snippet above so that all my pages loaded the JavaScript.

Finally, I settled on placing it in `App.razor`, and now all my JavaScript works on all pages.